# How to make a tooltip to show a static page fragment using Primefaces 5.x?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In my webapp I have to show rich tooltips, which means, tooltips with some text sometimes richly formatted, even with images or tables.

I planned to put the contents of the tooltips in .xhtml files, so it would be easier to reformat them when needed.

However, I couldn't find any examples or code samples showing this behavior. I suppose I have to combine certain components in order to reach the effect I desire, but could not figure it out.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: So you didn't just checked out showcase or users guide if PrimeFaces has a tooltip component?

Comment: I know that such a component exists, but in the showcase there was not any examples that correspond to my needs. Like, there are some examples of tooltips, but with simple and short text, not rich as I need and not from an external document. Anyways, I understand my question could be better written in order to avoid interpretations like yours. My fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, next time you have to read the Primefaces documentation before to question. It's very easy.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <h:outputText value="I must to look at Primefaces Showcase: " />
        <h:outputLink id="content" value="#">
            <h:outputText value="Primefaces" />
        </h:outputLink>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipContent" for="content">
            <ui:include src="include.xhtml" />
        </p:tooltip>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**include.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h2>Include tooltip</h2>
    <h:graphicImage value="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/main/images/logoBlue.svg.xhtml" />
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: As I said to BalusC, I did dig Primefaces showcase, but the examples existing there did not address my particular needs (a rich text from an external file). I indeed could be more careful when writing the question details, in order to avoid the idea that I didn't expend any time there. Anyways, I could not see the use of <ui:include/> in this context (something that was not in the samples) and for that I thank you for sharing your knowledge!